# How to add 'Views' in the forums page of bbPress (plugin)?

Tags: bbpress

I thought 'Views" was a pretty common item in a forum table.

Is there a way of enabling this or adding it to Wordpress + the bbpress plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

bbPress has never included the number of times a topic was viewed in the core project, and as such the plugin currently does not either. The primary reason is this causes an extra hit to the DB to bump the value of topic views +1 on each page-load.

This is something that could be built as plugin, or if enough requests come through the forums for this to be in the core project, it may make its way in eventually.